# Calculate age in jquery display in days months year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate in age of the person in days,months,year as of date May 2024. When the user selects the date of birth from the date picker days, months and year of the person has to be displayed in particular text boxes.
Year and month calculation works fine but days calculation is not working properly
Here is the code

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
                $("#XIStudentDOB").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (value, ui) {
                    var toDate = new Date(2024, 05, 01);
                var fromDate = new Date(value);
                var days = (toDate - fromDate) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
                var y = 365;
                var y2 = 31;
                var remainder = days % y;
                var casio = remainder % y2;
                year = (days - remainder) / y;
                month = (remainder - casio) / y2;
                     day = (toDate - fromDate)  / y;
                   var displayMonth = fromDate.getMonth()+1;
                    var DateString = fromDate.getDate() + "/" + displayMonth + '/' +                    fromDate.getFullYear();
        $("#XIStudentDOB").val(DateString);
                    $("#age").val(year);
                $("#months").val(month);
                     $("#days").val(day);
            },
            dateFormat: 'yy,mm,dd',
            defaultDate: '2000,01,01',
            maxDate: new Date((new Date).getFullYear(), 11, 31),
            yearRange: '2000:2016',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }); 
         });

       <input type="text" name="XIStudentDOB" id="XIStudentDOB" class="form-control" />
        <input type="text" name="yr" id="yr" maxlength="2" required=""  />Year
         <input type="text" name="month" id="month" maxlength="2"  required=""  />Months
         <input type="text" name="days" id="days"  maxlength="2"  required=""  />Days
```

How to calculate the days in from the date of birth using jquery

Comment: Have a look at this answer from @trincot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54538076/2610061 . It avoids many of the typical problems you can encounter in date calculations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Date() to calculate age work by the day,months,years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251325/javascript-date-to-calculate-age-work-by-the-day-months-years)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly! Here is a complete and corrected working code snippet for you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Age Calculator</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#XIStudentDOB").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (value, ui) {
                var toDate = new Date(2024, 4, 1);
                var fromDate = new Date(value);
                var timeDiff = Math.abs(toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime());
                var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

                var year = Math.floor(diffDays / 365);
                var remainderYear = diffDays % 365;
                var month = Math.floor(remainderYear / 30);
                var day = remainderYear % 30;

                $("#XIStudentDOB").val(value);
                $("#yr").val(year);
                $("#month").val(month);
                $("#days").val(day);
            },
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            defaultDate: '2000/01/01',
            maxDate: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), 11, 31),
            yearRange: '2000:2016',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="XIStudentDOB" id="XIStudentDOB" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="yr" id="yr" maxlength="2" required=""> Year
<input type="text" name="month" id="month" maxlength="2" required=""> Months
<input type="text" name="days" id="days" maxlength="2" required=""> Days

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is an image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biFP9.png)

Comment: This code works fine. But i have to calculate the age of the person based on may 2024 what will be age of person

Comment: Only days calculations is not happening the above script of mine

Comment: You can check my latest edit on this post; I have done what you asked for.

Comment: It is giving minus values. I want to calculate the age of the person as on May 2024

Comment: No, it's not. I also added an image example showing the result from May 2024, which shows a difference of 6 months and 1 day. There are no negative values in the answer

Comment: If u select the date of birth between 2000 to 2023 it gives minus value..

Comment: If the user selects date 25/05/2023 it has to show 1 year 0 months and day 5. as on may 2024 his age has to be completed

Comment: My above script shows year month calculation right only days calculation is not happening

Comment: okay i got it now i updated my answer and modified your code snippet check it now

Answer (score 0):

- Create an HTML form with an input field for entering the date of
  birth.
- Use jQuery to capture the input date when the user submits the
  form.
- Calculate the difference between the current date and the
  entered date of birth.
- Display the calculated number of days.

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dateForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  ```
               // Get the date of birth value from the input field
               var dob = new Date($('#dob').val());

               // Check if a valid date was entered
               if (!isNaN(dob.getTime())) {
                   // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
                   var today = new Date();
                   var difference = today - dob;

                   // Convert milliseconds to days
                   var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

                   // Display the result
                   $('#result').text('You have lived for ' + days + ' days.');
               } else {
                   $('#result').text('Please enter a valid date of birth.');
               }
           });
       });
  ```