# Get age from html field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a dialogue box popping up to to display age in years and months for the entered value. I have tried several ways but it still can't work out. I get NaN as the answer. Can someone help me out please?

My html:

```
<label for="dob">Child’s Date of birth</label>
<input class="form-control" type="date" name"dob" placeholder="Date of birth" id="dob" onblur"dateofBirth()"/>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function dateofBirth{
var dofBirth = document.getElementById("dob").value;
var age = (new Date() - dofBirth) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*365);
alert("The child's age is "+ age);
}
```

Comment: What value does `dofBirth` have (hint: It depends on what you type into the input). What do you expect to happen when you try to subtract it from `new Date`?

Comment: should it not be `alert("The child's age is" + age);`

Comment: @mornenel ... That was just an oversight. Was typing fast and responses came just a minute after the post.

Comment: For more help [`Calculating Age In Years,Months and Days`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833709/calculating-age-in-months-and-days) & [`Demo Fiddle using the code`](http://jsfiddle.net/4orxnv95/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that dofBirth is type String after the input. You need to turn it into a date for it to work as a date.

```
var age = (new Date - new Date(dofBirth))
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

First off, the date input method is not widely supported yet, nonetheless, chrome gives me "2014-11-05" as the value JS will get.

Thus, you could use badrequest400's method, but there seems to be a timezone adjustment with that. So I would suggest something like:

```
var tempStr = doBirth.split("-");
var age = (new Date() - new Date(tempStr[0], tempStr[1] - 1, tempStr[2])); // Plus your other calculations.
```

That minus one is necessary since months go from 0 - 11.